# Title and main text - intent Action_SEND in an android app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

So, I'm trying to share a title and the text of my article, via social apps like Viber, Whatsapp and so on. So, below is my code, and the problem is it only shares the main text, not the title. But it reads it, as you can see it on the share dialog (it's the text with the larger font). But as you can see on the 2nd screenshot, it only passes the main text. What can be the problem here?

http://prntscr.com/urd4z6
http://prntscr.com/urd57q

```
holder.imgShareM.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                        String s1 = holder.txt_short_desc.getText().toString();
                        String s2 = holder.txt_description.getText().toString();
                        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent();
                        sharingIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, s1);
                        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, s2);
                        activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share the article via:"));

 }
            });
```

EDIT: A little update. I tried adding my app link at the bottom via:

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.sharing_text) + "\n" +
                        "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName());
```

And now it sends only that. So, it seems to only sends the last thing.

Comment: You can do nothing. That is how some apps behave.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this line for adding the title to your email:

```java
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your Subject Here");
```

Comment: That works for emails, but for every other app it does nothing. Tried it already. But thanks.

Comment: @user2083882
I don't know what do you mean about "every other app"; what does mean title when you share a text in WhatsApp messenger?
in other apps but emails, you should add the title to the start of the text I guess

Comment: Well, I'm sharing an article, and the article has a title and the main text.

Comment: @user2083882 but you can not do anything for adding the title separately from the main text.
you should add that to the start of the text manually